# Why chaining is not working when passed as lambdas in predicate?

Tags: java-8, functional-programming

I am new in functional programming.
I want to understand which concept am I missing here.

```
    Stream<Employee> stream1 = getEmployeeListOne().stream();
    Stream<Employee> stream2 = getEmployeeListTwo().stream();
    Predicate<Employee>predicate=x->x.getFirstName().startsWith("L");
    //Below line is compile time error
    List<Employee>list=stream1.filter((x->x.getFirstName().startsWith("L")).or(x->x.getLastName().startsWith("L"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
    //Below line works well 
    //List<Employee>list2=stream1.filter(predicate.or(x->x.getLastName().startsWith("L"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It simply says lambda expression not expected here

Comment: What exactly is the problem? --- In the code presented, `stream1.filter(...)` is called twice. `Stream`s are one-time resources, so once they have been consumed once, they are "empty".

Comment: @Turing85 even when i comment the last line ,it is compilation error. I had uncommented here for posting. Thanks I have updated the question.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add the compilation error.

Comment: It just says lamdas are not expected

Comment: The syntax is incorrect. In the code presented, the first lambda is surronded by a pair of parenthesis. Replace `List<Employee>list=stream1.filter((x->x.getFirstName().startsWith("L")).or(x->x.getLastName().startsWith("L"))).collect(Collectors.toList());` with `List<Employee>list = stream1.filter(x -> x.getFirstName().startsWith("L") || x.getLastName().startsWith("L")).collect(Collectors.toList());`.

Comment: Ohh i see.It compiles fine now . But why .or works in the last line??

Comment: Because in the other example, we use a `Predicate`, initialized by a lambda. In the first example, we use a "raw" lambda. It is not yet a `Predicate`, just a lambda.

Comment: Ohhh that makes sense to me now.Thankss:)))))

Comment: @Turing85 You could make the lambda a predicate though, right? There should be some inline syntax for this as well.

Comment: @Bergi sure, we can cast the lambda: `((<Type-we-need>) <lambda-expression>)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Predicate` has the `or()` method.
A lambda does not.

If you assign the lambda to a variable of type `Predicate`, you’re fulfilling the implementation of `Predicate`’s single unimplemented method `test()`, which only then has an `or()` method.

Answer (score 0):

THis is how i have tried to do it, extract similar test condition in a method , make predicate return boolean of composite condition.

The chaining does work if you write

```
final Predicate<Employee> onlyEmpNameStarsWithL = employee -> nameStartsWithL(employee.firstName);// || nameStartsWithL(employee.lastName);
```

and then use full code as below:

```
List<Employee> allEmployeeWithLInName = employeeStream.filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .filter(onlyEmpNameStarsWithL.or(e -> nameStartsWithL(e.lastName)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        allEmployeeWithLInName.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Or the complete other approach

```
final Predicate<Employee> onlyEmpNameStarsWithL = 
employee -> nameStartsWithL(employee.firstName) || nameStartsWithL(employee.lastName);
```

helper method

```
    static boolean nameStartsWithL(String name) {
        return name != null && name.startsWith("L");
    }
```

Full source code

```
package examples;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

class Employee {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    public Employee(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

public class LambdaPredicate {
    static boolean nameStartsWithL(String name) {
        return name != null && name.startsWith("L");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> employeeList = Arrays.asList(
                new Employee("A", "P"),
                new Employee("B", "L"),
                null,
                new Employee("C", "Q"),
                new Employee("L", "I"),
                new Employee("L", "L")
        );

        final Predicate<Employee> onlyEmpNameStarsWithL = employee -> nameStartsWithL(employee.firstName) || nameStartsWithL(employee.lastName);
        Stream<Employee> employeeStream = employeeList.stream();

        List<Employee> allEmployeeWithLInName = employeeStream.filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .filter(onlyEmpNameStarsWithL)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        allEmployeeWithLInName.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Employee{firstName='B', lastName='L'}
Employee{firstName='L', lastName='I'}
Employee{firstName='L', lastName='L'}
```